# Why my <image> become <img> on appenChild ? [SVG]

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom

On context, i need to add an **SVGImageElement** (aka simple string) to a SVG group (`<g>`). So i transform my string to an HTMLNode and then add it to my group.

My problem is on the workflow, **my string `<image>` become an `<img>`** html element and unfortunatly i can't do anything with an `<img>` inside my SVG namespace (i need `x` `y` `height` `width`...)

I don't understand why this workflow overwrite my string ? Do i miss something ?

There is the string : `'<image id="ctrlLeft" xlink:href="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/48/000000/move.png" x="0" y="-200" height="200" width="200"></image>'`

I transform the string this way and add it to a  group :

```js
  var ctrlMove = '<image id="ctrlLeft" xlink:href="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/48/000000/move.png" x="0" y="-200" height="200" width="200"></image>';
  var gMove = document.createElement("g");
  gMove.setAttribute("id", "ctrlMove");
        
  var r = document.createRange();
  r.selectNodeContents(gMove);
  var f = r.createContextualFragment(ctrlMove);
  gMove.appendChild(f); // InnerHTML show <img> instead of <image>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess gMove element is created in HTML namespace, where `<image>` is legacy alias for `<img>`.

Try changing

```
var gMove = document.createElement("g");
```

to

```
var gMove = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
```

Comment: Well... Thank you :') So obvious